# Python - read a file and append it to a Dataframe line by line

Tags: python, email, pandas

Can I read a file with Python, and then directly append data from each line to a Pandas dataframe?

The data I want to parse is contained in the body of an email:

[image]

I tried using `RegEx` to capture the following data:

**Species**: `GB EAST cod, GB blackback`, etc

**Sector**: `NEFS 5`

**Pounds**: `954, 30,000`, etc

**Prices**: `$0.83, $0.07`, etc

and the **Date**: `09/01/2014`

but it proved very difficult to capture all of that...

I can get the **Date** easily since it'll always appear after `Sent:` I use RegEx to capture everything after `Sent:` and then `dateutil` to capture the date.

The **Sector** is easy enough too, I just have RegEx search for one of the 20 sectors and if it sees one of them captures it.

But capturing the species, pounds, and price data and making sure they line up correctly, AND putting them into a dataframe neatly is where I am stuck. So my thinking now is to just capture each line in the body of the email and break up what I capture into different columns for the dataframe.

I know that isn't the cleanest capture but I'd rather get too much of the data and just have to delete some manually later than not get enough of it.

So my question is: with Python can I read a file and transfer everything I read into a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: How do you want the second line (the trade) handled?

Comment: I think the best thing for those, and what I've done in the past for other data files, is to just add the second lb amount (the `trade for 1,830 lbs` piece) to the Price column of the dataframe. Instead of asking for money for their available amount of fish they ask for other fish. So putting that value in the Price column makes sense right?

Answer (score 1):

This is an overly-specific function I made for reading the fish section of your email once I put it in a text file. It assumes you've already pulled out the date and the sector.

It might not work exactly for your implementation, but hopefully the use of python string methods will get you in the right direction, and show you how to add it all into a DataFrame.

```
def fish_to_frame(fish_file, sector, date):
    # Initialize some lists
    species = []
    pounds = []
    prices = []
    date = pd.to_datetime(date, infer_datetime_format=True)
    with open(fish_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            # Fish: weight @ price
            fish, remainder = line.split(':')
            if '@' in remainder:
                weight, price = remainder.split('@')
            if 'trade' in remainder:
                weight, price = remainder.split('to ')
            weight = weight.strip(' lbs')
            species.append(fish)
            pounds.append(weight)
            prices.append(price)
    fish_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Species':species,
                              'Sector':sector,
                              'Pounds':pounds,
                              'Prices':prices,
                              'Date':date})
    return fish_frame
```

You could do some additional steps in there to convert the weights, etc to numeric, etc as well. Hope this helps!

And an additional step could be combining this with an existing DataFrame with those columns already existing. But adding new entries line by line would be slow(er).

Comment: So reading through your code it looks like it should work perfect to capture the right pieces from the email, but unfortunately it doesn't. It fails on the line `fish, remainder = line.split(':')` with the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Comment: On a side note, overly-specific is exactly what I was thinking of writing: just endless `if` loops looking for one of the 20 sectors, looking for numbers with $ signs, looking for numbers following @'s, etc.

Comment: The only reason that would happen is if there's multiple ':' to split on. Your example doesn't have any examples that have more than one colon, so I'm not sure why that would happen. Try printing that line instead of assigning the output and see what it else it is splitting on.

Comment: Ohhh when I `print(f)` I get `f: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Z://stuff\\20140905-FW_ NEFS 5 Available Fish-964.eml' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`. Before when I ran into this I had to do another line that says `b = f.read`. Let me try that

Comment: Edit: it didn't work, now it says `str object has no attribute 'message_from_string'` even though that line works perfectly in another script

Comment: If you `print(f)`, you just get python telling you about the file object named `f`. Try printing the results of the failing `line.split(':')`

Comment: Ohh gotcha. Doing `print("line.split is:", line.split(':'))` produces: `line.split is: ['Delivered-To', ' name.name@email.com\n']
line.split is: ['Received', ' by 10.224.132.198 with SMTP id c6csp1560qat;\n'`... So it's capturing stuff outside that screenshot of the email I posted in my question...

Comment: Ah. Scraping the entire email is a whole different matter. However, if you'd like it to ignore all the lines that aren't what you're trying to put into dataframe, you could add after `for line in f:` this: `if (':' in line) and ('lbs' in line):`

Comment: Ohhh ok now I'm starting to really understand how specific some of this code needs to be (I need to parse 100's of these text file emails, all of them formatted differently)... That seemed to work, but not perfect, it printed: `line.split is: [' *   GB EAST cod', ' 954 lbs =40 =240.83\n']` and then failed on `weight = weight.strip(' lbs')` with the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'weight' referenced before assignment`.....which says that the variable `weight` was used before, but I don't understand. Yes it was used before, but in order to acquire the data we want..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138754/discussion-between-jammeth-q-and-theprowler).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you have data in a file, you can use pandas.read_csv('filename.csv'). Check [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for details.

Comment: That has yielded a plethora of errors, all due to `read_csv` trying to read the wrong kind of argument. That's even with trying to read the file path, the email page itself, the email page saved as a txt file, the raw text of the email, and the email as a `str()`. So I don't know if that's my best option. Does `pd.read_csv` even read data directly into a dataframe like I want? Can it transpose sentences into a data table?